Как можно увеличить скорость нахождения пискеля на экране в AHK (Auto Hot Key)
Как можно в этом ahk скрипте максимально  увеличить скорость нахождения пискеля на экране?
Может что-то тут лишнее?
#NoEnv 
#persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
#KeyHistory 0
ListLines Off
SetBatchLines, -1
SetKeyDelay, -1, -1
SetMouseDelay, -1
SetDefaultMouseSpeed, 0
SetWinDelay, -1
SetControlDelay, -1
SendMode Input
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
SoundBeep, 300, 200
SoundBeep, 400, 200

;HOTKEYS
key_stay_on :=  "F1"        ; self explanatory      
key_hold_mode   :=  "5"     ; scan will only scan if "key_hold" is pressed
key_fastclick   :=  "XButton1"      ; self explanatory (on/off beep sound only)
key_off     :=  "F4"        ; self explanatory  
key_gui_hide    :=  "Home"      ; hides gui (graphical user interface)      
key_exit    :=  "End"       ; self explanatory      
key_hold    :=  "LAlt"  ; key that you hold to scan (example "T")   

;SETTINGS
pixel_box   :=  4       ; Keep between min 3 and max 8      
pixel_sens  :=  25  ; higher/lower = more/less color sensitive      
pixel_color :=  0xA145A3    ; yellow="0xFEFE40", purple="0xA145A3"
tap_time    :=  10      ; Delay in ms between shots when triggered

;DO NOT TOUCH?
Gui,2:Font,Cdefault,Fixedsys
Gui,2:Color,Black
Gui,2:Color, EEAA99
Gui,2:Add,Progress, x10 y20 w100 h23 Disabled BackgroundGreen vC3
Gui,2:Add,Text, xp yp wp hp cYellow BackgroundTrans Center 0x200 vB3 gStart,ON
Gui,2:Add,Progress, x10 y20 w100 h23 Disabled BackgroundGreen vC2
Gui,2:Add,Text, xp yp wp hp cYellow BackgroundTrans Center 0x200 vB2 gStart,HOLD MODE
Gui,2:Add,Progress, xp yp wp hp Disabled BackgroundRED vC1
Gui,2:Add,Text, xp yp wp hp cYellow BackgroundTrans Center 0x200 vB1 gStart,OFF
Gui,2: Show, x10 y1 w200 h60
Gui 2:+LastFound +ToolWindow +AlwaysOnTop -Caption
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
2Guiescape:
2Guiclose:
leftbound := 1280 / 2 - pixel_box
rightbound := 1280 / 2 + pixel_box
topbound := 720 / 2 - pixel_box
bottombound := 720 / 2 + pixel_box
hotkey, %key_stay_on%, stayon
hotkey, %key_hold_mode%, holdmode
hotkey, %key_off%, offloop
hotkey, %key_gui_hide%, guihide
hotkey, %key_exit%, terminate
Hotkey, % key_fastclick, fastclick
return
start:
gui,2:submit,nohide
terminate:
SoundBeep, 300, 200
SoundBeep, 200, 200
Sleep 400
exitapp
stayon:
SoundBeep, 300, 200
settimer, loop2, off
settimer, loop1, 100
GuiControl,2: hide,B1
GuiControl,2: hide,C1
GuiControl,2: hide,B2
GuiControl,2: hide,C2
GuiControl,2: show,B3
GuiControl,2: show,C3
return
holdmode:
SoundBeep, 300, 200
settimer, loop1, off
settimer, loop2, 100
GuiControl,2: hide,B1
GuiControl,2: hide,C1
GuiControl,2: show,B2
GuiControl,2: show,C2
GuiControl,2: hide,B3
GuiControl,2: hide,C3
return
offloop:
SoundBeep, 300, 200
settimer, loop1, off
settimer, loop2, off
GuiControl,2: show,B1
GuiControl,2: show,C1
GuiControl,2: hide,B2
GuiControl,2: hide,C2
GuiControl,2: hide,B3
GuiControl,2: hide,C3
return
guihide:
GuiControl,2: hide,B1
GuiControl,2: hide,C1
GuiControl,2: hide,B2
GuiControl,2: hide,C2
GuiControl,2: hide,B3
GuiControl,2: hide,C3
return

loop1:
PixelSearch()
return

loop2:
While GetKeyState(key_hold, "P"){
PixelSearch()
}
return

fastclick:
SoundBeep, 300, 200
toggle := !toggle
return
#if toggle
*~$LButton::
sleep 100
While GetKeyState("LButton", "P"){
Click
sleep 10
}
return
#if

PixelSearch() {
global
PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, leftbound, topbound, rightbound, bottombound, pixel_color, pixel_sens, Fast RGB
If !(ErrorLevel)
{
If !GetKeyState("LButton")
{
click
sleep %tap_time%
}
}
return
}

